# exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows in a triger execution

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, mod-plsql, plsql-psp

I am creating a trigger for `auto_generating` `prod_id` from `prod_summery`
the given table is

```
PROD_ID CHAR(8 BYTE)    No      1   
PRODUCT_TITLE   VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)   No      2   
PRODUCT_SUMMERY VARCHAR2(150 BYTE)  No      3   
INTEREST_TYPE   CHAR(1 BYTE)    No      4   
INTEREST_RATE   NUMBER(4,2) No      5   
SECURITY_REQD   CHAR(1 BYTE)    No      6   
MIN_LOAN_AMT    NUMBER(11,2)    No      7   
MAX_LOAN_AMT    NUMBER(11,2)    No      8   
TERM_MIN    INTERVAL YEAR(2) TO MONTH   No      9   
TERM_MAX    INTERVAL YEAR(2) TO MONTH   No      10  
REPAYMENT_FREQUENCY INTERVAL YEAR(2) TO MONTH   No      11  
REPAYMENT_AMT   NUMBER(11,2)    No      12  
EARLY_REPAY_ALLOWED CHAR(1 BYTE)    No      13  
MIN_AGE_LIMIT   NUMBER(2,0) No      14  
MAX_AGE_LIMIT   NUMBER(2,0) No      15  
RESIDENT    RESIDENT_VARRAY No      16  
PROD_START_DT   DATE    Yes     17  
PROD_END_DT DATE    Yes     18  
PROD_STATUS CHAR(1 BYTE)    No      19
```

**Trigger**

```
create or replace TRIGGER LOAN_PROD_ID_TR1 
    BEFORE INSERT ON LOAN_PROD_TAB
   for each row
    DECLARE
      v_length number(2):=LENGTH(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY)-
         LENGTH(REPLACE(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,' ',' '))+1;
         V_W2 VARCHAR2(10);
        V_W3 VARCHAR2(10);
     V_W4 VARCHAR2(10);
      V_W5 VARCHAR2(10);
V_W6 VARCHAR2(10);
 V_CON VARCHAR2(10);
V_CON1 VARCHAR2(10);
V_CON2 VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
 IF v_length=1 THEN
 SELECT 'CBIS'||LPAD(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,4) INTO :NEW.PROD_ID FROM 
 LOAN_PROD_TAB;
  ELSIF v_length=2 THEN
  V_W2:=SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,'(\S*)(\s)',1,2),1,2);
  V_W3:=SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,'(\S*)'),1,2);
    SELECT 'CBIS'||LPAD(V_W2,4,V_W3) INTO :NEW.PROD_ID FROM LOAN_PROD_TAB;
    ELSIF v_length=3 THEN
  V_W2:=SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,'(\S*)($)'),1,1);
   V_W3:=SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,'(\S*)(\s)',1,2),1,2);  
   V_W4:=SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,'(\S*)'),1,2);
    V_CON:=CONCAT(V_W3,V_W2);
   SELECT 'CBIS'||LPAD(V_W4,4,V_CON) INTO :NEW.PROD_ID FROM LOAN_PROD_TAB;
   ELSIF v_length=4 THEN
    V_W2:=SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,'(\S*)'),1,1);
     V_W3:=SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,'(\S*)(\s)',1,2),1,1);
   V_W4:=SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,'(\S*)(\s)',1,3),1,1);
   V_W5:=SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,'(\S*)($)'),1,1);
    V_CON:=CONCAT(V_W2,V_W3);
      V_CON1:=CONCAT(V_W4,V_W5);
    V_CON2:=CONCAT(V_CON,V_CON1);
    SELECT 'CBIS'||LPAD(V_CON2,4) INTO :NEW.PROD_ID FROM LOAN_PROD_TAB;
        ELSE
        V_W2:=SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,'(\S*)'),1,1);
         V_W3:=SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,'(\S*)(\s)',1,2),1,1);
         V_W4:=SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,'(\S*)(\s)',1,3),1,1);
      V_W5:=SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,'(\S*)(\s)',1,4),1,1);
      V_CON:=CONCAT(V_W2,V_W3);
    V_CON1:=CONCAT(V_W4,V_W5);
    V_CON2:=CONCAT(V_CON,V_CON1);
         SELECT 'CBIS'||LPAD(V_CON2,4) INTO :NEW.PROD_ID FROM LOAN_PROD_TAB;
         END  IF;
     END;
```

Comment: please some one find reason of that error

Comment: The code would be easier to follow and debug if you applied some formatting rather than just placing random amounts of whitespace in front of each line, and used lowercase.

Comment: By the way, the standard string type in Oracle is `VARCHAR2`. You should only use `CHAR` if you have a specific business requirement to store trailing blank spaces for strings shorter than the maximum length, and I have never seen this requirement ever.

Answer (score 4):

your error is caused by the select statements, e.g.

```
SELECT 'CBIS'||LPAD(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,4) INTO :NEW.PROD_ID
FROM LOAN_PROD_TAB;
```

if there is more than one record in the table you will get an error as you are selecting everything from the table.

You shouldn't need to do a select here, you should be able to just do

```
:NEW.PROD := 'CBIS'||LPAD(:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY,4);
```

Answer (score 1):

`TOO-MANY-ROWS` is returned by one of `SELECT` statements. Basically, no wonder - none of them contains the `WHERE` clause.

On the other hand, I think that you shouldn't use `SELECT` at all; trigger is on LOAN_PROD_TAB, and you're selecting from it - that leads to a mutating table error. Instead, you should rewrite them (example based on your first SELECT) into

```
   :NEW.prod_id := 'CBIS' || LPAD (:NEW.PRODUCT_SUMMERY, 4);
```

Oh, yes - one more thing: for your own sake, learn how to properly format code. Using such an unreadable mess is a nightmare.

Comment: Do that :) It'll make your (and our) life somewhat less complicated :)